# Type mismatch issue while adding to coredata array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I have added the data in an alertview textfield to the object of coredata like so...

```
let category = Category(context: self.context)
category.alertTextFieldData = (alertController.textFields?.first?.text)!
```

But now I wanted to add this to a CoreData Array which I am trying to do like this...

```
self.people.append(category.alertTextFieldData!)
```

But when I do this, it gives the error..

```
'Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Category''
```

where `Category` is the entity name.

So how can I solve this issue...?

Comment: you added same question 2 hours before.

Comment: yes..but I got further by making the coredata object and tried to solve the issue...but the issue still persisted..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace this line:**

```
self.people.append(category)
```

**From:**

```
self.people.append(category.alertTextFieldData!)
```

Comment: Ok..but one doubt...if I do this will that data of the textfield itself will be saved...?

Comment: Yes, When you fetch values from core-data you will receive the `Category` object and you can retrieve again from `category.alertTextFieldData`

Comment: Ok..@Salman Ghumsani   One question..So if this is done...self.people.append(category) then will the data in the textField be stored in people or will I have to do anything also for saving that textfield data to people array..?

Comment: No, You don't need to do anything, 
Every object has its own properties and behavior `people` has the `textField ` data via `category` object.

Comment: Happy to help :)