# Adding a string variable to an array of type NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I am able to add a string variable to a string array like so....

```
self.stringArray.append(self.stringVar)
```

But how can I add a string variable to an `NSManagedObject` array..?

Or should I in such a case use something else instead of the string variable...?

Comment: You aren't the author of these questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/46336536/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46338455/1187415 by any chance? – An NSManagedObject array contains NSManagedObjects, not strings. Adding a string variable makes no sense. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have seen that question..but it has no answer...

Comment: Again: Adding a *string* to an array of *managed objects* makes no sense. Please update the question with enough information that we can see what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: martin..you mean it is not possible...? if not can we achieve that using any other means...?